# spfx pnp search API: Search by content type and part URL

Tags: search-results, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a requirement to makes an SPFX search webpart that can be searched by content type and also partial item url but it has to only return a specific content type from all sites accept root.

The content type is a list item and I'm using urldepth>1 to exclude root. However it returns no results when I try to search for site name or other parts of the url

I cant share all the code unfortunately due to the nature of the project.

Here it the basic query that the search object uses to generate the initial result set...

```
testQuery = "contentTypeId:0x0100BB00A852FB374E4FA11A71309A944B75* urldepth>1";
let _search: Search = new Search(this.props.wpContext.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl); 
let _results = await _search.execute({
      Querytext: testQuery,
      EnablePhonetic: true,
      TrimDuplicates: false,
      RowsPerPage: itemLimit,
      RowLimit: itemLimit,
      EnableSorting: true,
      StartRow: currentStartRow,
      SelectProperties: [ Constants.fieldName_Title, Constants.fieldName_SiteUrl, Constants.fieldName_ProjectStatus, Constants.fieldName_ProjectProposer, Constants.fieldName_Created, Constants.fieldName_SiteRelativeUrl ],
      SortList: [
        {
          'Property': Constants.fieldName_Created,
          'Direction': 1
        }
      ]   
    });
```

And in addition they can type into a text box to append keywords to the query. However it didnt work in the webpart so I took it to the modern search page to figure out if I'd made an error in my webpart somewhere

```
https://tenent.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/_layouts/15/search.aspx?q="contentTypeId:0x0100BB00A852FB374E4FA11A71309A944B75* urldepth>1  project1"
```

This returns no results but when searched for separately it seems to work. I just cant seem to get them working togeather in a single query.

Appreciate any help you can give on this one.

Cheers!

Comment: Addition: sorry forgot to mention I'm using PNP JS (import { Web, Search } from '@pnp/sp';) and I following some more testing I dont think that by search in SharePoint modern search by a partial URL it doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to fill between filters AND:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/zvi/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx#k=Title%3Dbatman%20AND%20ContentType%3ADocument#l=1029
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was correct and something i should have sheared was some of URLs i was search. Many of the sites contained hyphens which where being read as excludes. For this I lopped through the string and replaced hyphens with spaces.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.